# sed command doesn't work in shell script

Tags: shell, sed

I have a shell script that looks like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $1/*.html; do
   echo "Working on $file ..."

   # delete headers in html files.
   sed -n '1,9d' $file

   # delete the last 4 lines of the file.
   sed -n -e :a -e '1,4!{P;N;D;};N;ba'

   # ant runs regex task on all apt files
   ant -Dtarget.file=$file

   # all .html are changed to .md
   mv $file `echo $file | sed 's/\(.*\.\)html/\1md/'` ;

done
```

but the script hangs on the first sed command and I have to force exit. I'm wondering if there's anything wrong about the way I've set this up?

If I remove the first two sed commands, I can run the other parts of the script, including that final one with a sed command in it.

Comment: The `mv` makes me cringe due to the useless and expensive fork to yet another `sed`. If you just want to replace an extension in a filename stored in a variable, use `mv $file ${file%.html}.md`.

Answer (score 4):

I think you'll find it's hanging on the *second* `sed`, where you don't provide a file name to work on. In other words, it will take its standard input from the terminal.

You won't get output from the first `sed` since `-n` prevents the default printing of the pattern space. If you're trying to change the actual *file* rather than output the changes to standard output, you need the `-i` inplace editor.

If you can't use the inplace option, you'll have to do something like:

```
sed -n '1,9d' ${file} >${file}.tmp0
sed -n -e :a -e '1,4!{P;N;D;};N;ba' ${file}.tmp0 >${file}
rm -f ${file}.tmp0
```

This uses a temporary file for making the changes except for the last change, which overwrites the original file. Keep in mind that this *changes* the original - if that's not what you want, you can change the second `sed` to output to `${file}.tmp2` but you'll have to adjust your subsequent commands to take that into account.

If you really want to delete the first nine and last four lines of a file, you can also use something like:

```
head --lines=-4 oldfile.txt | tail --lines=+10 >newfile.txt
```

provided you have a `[rd]ecent` implementation of `head/tail`. The `head` prints all but the last four lines and the `tail` starts printing at line ten.

Comment: You are right, it didn't hang when I added the filename. However, still no lines were deleted from the head or tail of the files. I unfortunately do not have a decent `head` ... I mean the shell command :) ... but I managed to use `tail` for getting rid of the headers and ant-based regex for snipping the lines at the end.

Comment: @user766353, no lines were deleted since you're not replacing the file with the output of `sed`. `sed` normally writes the changes to standard output (rather than changing the original file). What you'd normally see on the output is those changes but, since you've used `-n` to suppress the default pattern space output, they won't appear. See my update for a solution (making sure the file itself is updated).

Answer (score 0):

What command are you running?  If nothing matches the file glob, then it will physically insert the unexpanded string there.

For example, try this:

```
$ for i in foo/*.bar; do echo $i; done
foo/*.bar
```

So your sed script is bombing out because the file name it is receiving doesn't exist, which means it will act as if no file argument was specified (ie stdin).

Comment: If the file doesn't exist, I'm pretty certain `sed` doesn't act as if you specified no file, instead it complains bitterly :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line to:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
```

This will show you each command as bash executes it, after all expansions have taken place.

My guess is that `$1/*.html` isn't matching any files; hence the sed line evaluates to just `sed -n '1,9d'` and so sed is trying to read from stdin

Comment: No, actually it will expand the $1 okay (to possibly an empty string) and leave the `*` untouched, in which case you'll get an error, unless you actually _have_ a literal `*.html` file which is both unlikely and unwise :-)

Comment: But as @paxdiablo also said, the actual root problem here is  almost certainly that it's hanging on the second sed. Using `bash -x` is a handy troubleshooting technique though.